# fstab mount drive as my /home

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab

I am trying to:

- mount my 2TB external USB hard drive as my home directory at `/home/peter`
- ensure that the home directory is owned by me (not root)
- do all this automatically at bootup

Currently:

- my drive is formatted to `ext4`
- my drive is empty
- I am running debian 7

I can reformat to another filesystem type if necessary, but I want to use the full 2TB on the drive.

The following `fstab` line mounts the drive incorrectly owned by `root`:

```
UUID=xxxx /home/peter ext4 nodev,nosuid 0 2
```

How can I mount the drive so that it is owned by `peter` (that's my login user on the PC)?

Comment: i'm trying to mount the external disk at `/home/peter`. i don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: The output of `ls -ld /home /home/peter` once mounted would help clarify this question.

Comment: No idea if this will work but you could try chowning /dev/sdX to your user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution was simply to chown the home directory after the mount took place:

```
$ chown peter:peter /home/peter
```

while using the following fstab settings:

```
UUID=xxxx /home/peter ext4 defaults 0 2
```

this hadn't worked before with other fstab settings, but now `/home/peter` remains owned by `peter` each time i restart (previously root kept taking ownership of this directory on restart).

Comment: The "root taking ownership" is rather obvious - when the filesystem is not mounted, any changes to the directory pertain to the mount point itself (and not to the filesystem that might get mounted there one fine day). That's why answer by @Pravin states **Once mounted**, change ownership.

Comment: it was not obvious to me - i did `chown peter:peter /path` before mounting but then after the mount it was back to `root root`. this may have been because the ownership of the directories on the drive default to `root` unless otherwise set?

Answer (score 3):

Try this as an /etc/fstab entry:

```
/path/to/device /mount/point/for/two2tbHDD ext4 umask=permissions,gid=peters_group_id,uid=peters_id 0 0
```

Once mounted, change ownership:

```
chown peter: /mount/point/for/two2tbHDD
```

Then change peter's home directory using

```
usermod -m -d /mount/point/for/two2tbHDD
```

Comment: Why not mounting to `/home/peter`?

Comment: @peterph yes.. /mount/point/for/two2tbHDD can be /home/peter too..